# Aligning multiple divs to bottom of parent div

Tags: css, html, styles

I have multiple child divs within a parent div.  Using **CSS**, is it possible to vertically align all of the child divs to the bottom of the parent container so that something like the following would be displayed:

[image]

The height of the child divs will be unknown (dynamic).

```
<p>Top of page</p>
<div id="container">
<div class="message">Message 4</div>
<div class="message">Message 3</div>
<div class="message">Message 2</div>
<div class="message">Message 1</div>
</div>
<p>Bottom of page</p>
```

style below:

```
#container {

    height: 500px;

    }
```

[Problem demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/49RqX/).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the following styles for the container

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: bottom;
```

[Solution demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/49RqX/1/).